# Avoiding duplicate with Many-to-Many through table in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to build an app where users can create 'contests' (think of these as elections), fill the ballot with candidates, and then vote on them but instead of casting a single vote for one candidate, rank them in order of preference.

This is my model so far:

```
class Contest(models.Model):
    contest_text = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Start Date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contest_text


class Candidate(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidates')
    candidate_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.candidate_name


class Ballot(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ballots')
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(Candidate, through='Preference')


class Preference(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ballot = models.ForeignKey(Ballot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    candidate_preference = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

However, I'd like to avoid the Preference table from having two rows for the different candidates where the preference is also the same. I.e. on the same ballot it should NOT be allowed that:

- John Doe, preference=1
- Foo Bar, preference=1

Do I just need to control this in the HTML when someone is submitting a vote? Of course, the above should be allowed but ONLY if those two votes came from different people. I'd prefer to control this in the database as well, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think I stumbled onto an answer...

adding:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('candidate', 'ballot', 'candidate_preference')
```

makes is so any of the foreign keys or preferences have to be different.

Now the only thing is to make sure someone can't put in the same candidate from the same ballot under two different preferences. I suppose I could remove 'candidate_preference' from the unique_together attribute and that would accomplish what I want since each voter will only cast one ballot for each contest.

Comment: That's the solution. But why did you include the preference in the unique constraint if you only want to allow one preference per candidate and ballot? However, don't you want to relate the preferences to users?

Comment: Eventually, users (i.e voters) will be linked to ballots so implicitly there will be a constraint on users. For now, anonymous users can submit ballots so there is no class to store in the db.